# how to fix this error on vs code json settings Vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, visual-studio-code

Hi every one please i debute in VueJs vs i have this error in VS CODE  see in the image below thank you for answering me

[image: Error Preview]

Comment: in JSON every key must have a value, `emmet.triggerExpansion` has no value

Comment: While images show what is needed, they can be removed by time and your question loses part of information possible useful for future readers. The code should be placed as text (formatted as code), so it creates [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Never post code/errors as image.

Comment: ok i'm new in stackOverflow it's why thank you for the remark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every key in JSON must have a value. emmet.triggerExpansion does not have a value.
Change it.

For example.
"emmet.triggerExpansion": {},

Comment: no problem have been detected thank you for answering me good job